# Why the background of a texture gets black if the alpha channel gets changed in the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following texture which has transparency and it renders okay.

[image]

I want to fade this texture by changing the displayed alpha channel of each pixel, so I wrote this on the fragment shader

```
void main()
{
  fragColor = texture(uTexture, texturePosition);
  fragColor.a = uAlpha;
}
```

This works as expected, except now where the texture is transparent it renders like it's behind something that is black

[image]

I'm missing something? Why adding an alpha channel changes the background of the texture to black?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I don't understand why this works

```
void main()
{
  fragColor = texture(uTexture, texturePosition);
  fragColor *= vec4(uAlpha);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely you have to enable blending on rendering API: https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Blending